# "The car/the guy behind" VS "The car/the guy behind us"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

**Context 1:** Let's say me and my friend are in my moving car, and there is a car behind us; and I think that car is following us. Can I say either,

> *"The car behind us is following us"*

or,

> *"The car behind is following us"*

I am sure we can say, "The car behind us is following us." How about, "The car behind is following us"? Do you think it is okay?

**Context 2:** Let's say I am walking with my friend on a street.I suddenly stumbled, and my friend asked what had happened. Can I say these interchangeably,

> *"A guy behind pushed me"*

or

> *"A guy behind me pushed me"*

Again, I know we can say "A guy behind me pushed me"; but I wonder if we can say, "A guy behind push me."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "us" or "me" can be omitted here. It clarifies what "behind" refers to. In some cases omission of such a word can lead to ambiguity, but here there is no reasonable lack of clarity -- no reasonable person would actually misunderstand. teh "me" or "us" is clearly implied.